# VBA doesn't work when looping through files (subscript out of range)

Tags: vba, excel

I just have started using vba.

Googled for a long time to find an answer.
I have written code for copying cells from one sheet into new one. 
I have to do it for every file in a folder.

So I try to use looping. However in a middle of a process error occurs (subscript out of range)

Here is my code that works for one file.

```vb
Sub add()

    Sheets.add.Name = "Good"
    GetBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Sheets("Good").Range("A1") = GetBook
    Sheets("Report Details").Range("E6:E8").Copy
    With Sheets("Good").Range("B1")
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    End With

    Sheet2.Activate
    Range(Range("A1").End(xlDown), Range("H1").End(xlDown)).Copy
    With Sheets("Good").Range("E1")
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    End With

End Sub
```

Here I try to loop it but it doesn't work, problem occurs here in the first code when looping

```
With Sheets("Good").Range("E1")
```

Looping code

```vb
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\Maxim Osipov\Documents\Mckinsey\BorisT\Project 3(Smart city solutions)\VBA collecting" 'change to suit
    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then FolderPath = FolderPath + "\"
    Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename)
        'Call a subroutine here to operate on the just-opened workbook
        Call add
        Filename = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: ***Welcome to Stack Overflow!*** Looks to me like you're trying to copy 3 cells `("E6:E8")` into 1 cell `("B1")`.

Comment: @braX - He's *creating* a worksheet named `Good` in the first line.

Comment: Also, there is no object named `Sheet2` in your code sample.  If you are trying to refer to a *worksheet* named `Sheet2` then use: `Sheets("Sheet2").Activate`...

Comment: The same problem if I copy 3 cells into 3 cells and I do create a Good worksheet yes

Comment: The same problem if copy 3 cells into 3 cells

Comment: You're doing good for having just started. Referring to different types of objects takes some getting used to.  Here's a helpful link: [10 ways to reference Excel workbooks and sheets using VBA](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/)

Comment: I take back my first comment - I guess the "3 into 1" wasn't an issue.  The `Sheet2` thing *will* be a problem.

Comment: Sheet2 is an index of a sheet, I can’t use sheet name because it differs for every file, but index is the same (Sheet2)

Comment: And it works for one file properly

Comment: Is `Sheet2` in the workbooks being opened, or the workbook holding the code?  As an index it will only look at the workbook holding the code (`ThisWorkbook`).  If the sheet in the book being opened is always the second sheet in tab order you could use `Worksheets(2)`

Comment: `If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then FolderPath = FolderPath + "\"` this line isn't really needed as you've manually entered the path - just use `....t 3(Smart city solutions)\VBA collecting\"`.  Also use `&` to concatenate rather `+` - not a problem here, but good practice (if used on numbers it will add them together).

Answer (score 0):

Try this slight variation:

```
Sub add()

    'Sheets.add.Name = "Good"
    Sheets("Good").Range("A1") = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Sheets("Report Details").Range("E6:E8").Copy
    Sheets("Good").Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address, Range("H1").End(xlDown).Address).Copy
    Sheets("Good").Range("E1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Sheets("Good").Range("E1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

End Sub
```

### See also:

- Microsoft : [Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel)
- [10 ways to reference Excel workbooks and sheets using VBA](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/)
- MSDN : [Refer to Sheets by Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/refer-to-sheets-by-name)
- MSDN : [How to Reference Cells and Ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221357(v=office.11).aspx)
- MSDN : [Range.Copy Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel)

Answer (score 0):

I was having some trouble figuring out which workbook some of your sheets were in - the ones being opened, or the one being pasted to.

This code will loop through the xlsx files in your folder and copy the ranges to the workbook holding the VBA code.
I added a function to check if the `Good` worksheet already exists and use that if it does.

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    FolderPath = "C:\Users\Maxim Osipov\Documents\Mckinsey\BorisT\Project 3(Smart city solutions)\VBA collecting\"
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")
    Do While FileName <> ""
        Set WB = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName, False, True) 'Not updating links & is read-only.
        'You can't create two sheets with the same name,
        'so check if it exists first.
        If WorkSheetExists("Good") Then
            Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Good")
        Else
            'Add a worksheet to the workbook holding this code.
            Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            WS.Name = "Good"
        End If
        'Pass the workbook and worksheet references to the procedure.
        Add WB, WS
        WB.Close SaveChanges:=False
        FileName = Dir
    Loop

End Sub

Public Sub Add(WrkBk As Workbook, wrkSht As Worksheet)

    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With wrkSht

        'Find the last cell.
        'You could use "LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row"
        'but not sure how much data is in the Sheet2.
        Set LastCell = .Cells.Find("*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              LookAt:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False)
        If LastCell Is Nothing Then
            LastRow = 1
        Else
            LastRow = LastCell.Row + 1
        End If

        .Cells(LastRow, 1) = WrkBk.Name

        WrkBk.Worksheets("Report Details").Range("E6:E8").Copy
        .Cells(LastRow, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

        With WrkBk.Worksheets(2)
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)).Copy
        End With
        With .Cells(LastRow, "E")
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        End With

    End With

End Sub

Public Function WorkSheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional WrkBk As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    If WrkBk Is Nothing Then
        Set WrkBk = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wrkSht = WrkBk.Worksheets(SheetName)
        WorkSheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)
        Set wrkSht = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

If you can only use the `Sheet2` reference in the workbook being opened this function will find it:

```
Public Function GetWorkSheet(sCodeName As String, Optional wrkBook As Workbook) As Worksheet

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    If wrkBook Is Nothing Then
        Set wrkBook = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    For Each wrkSht In wrkBook.Worksheets
        If wrkSht.CodeName = sCodeName Then
            Set GetWorkSheet = wrkSht
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wrkSht

End Function
```

To use it just change this line at the bottom of the `Add` procedure:

```
With WrkBk.Worksheets(2)
```

to

```
With GetWorkSheet("Sheet2", WrkBk)
```

Comment: Man, thanks a lot, you saved my life, hope to pay you back in future!!!

Comment: Good stuff.  Feel free to tick as accepted answer if it is.  Just finished writing my own question - the process of writing it out has hopefully given me the answer so no need to post it now... took me so long to write it though that I wanted to at least mention it somewhere. :D

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice (and warmly recommended) not to use `Activate`/`ActiveXXX`/`Select`/`Selection` pattern and take advantage of fully qualified range reference up to workbook one

so you could refactor your `add()` sub as follows (explanations in comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub add(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim repDetRngToCopy As Range, sht2RngToCopy As Range

    With ws 'reference passed worksheet
        Set repDetRngToCopy = .Parent.Worksheets("Report Details").Range("E6:E8") 'set needed range in "Report Details" worksheet of the same workbook the currently referenced sheet (i.e. the passed one) belongs to
        With .Parent.Worksheets(2) 'reference Sheet2 worksheet of the same workbook the currently referenced sheet belongs to
            Set sht2RngToCopy = .Range(Range("A1").End(xlDown), .Range("H1").End(xlDown)) 'set needed range in currently referenced sheet (i.e. Sheet2)
        End With

        'now start filling cells of referenced sheet (i.e. the passed one)
        .Range("A1") = .Name

        repDetRngToCopy.Copy 'copy from the range previously defined in "Report Details"
        .Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True ' paste in currently referenced sheet

        sht2RngToCopy.Copy 'copy from the range previously defined in Sheet2
        .Range("E1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues + xlPasteFormats 'paste in currently referenced sheet

        .Name = "Good" ' name currently referenced sheet
    End With
End Sub
```

and consequently slightly change your "main" sub where you call it as follows:

```
Do While Filename <> ""
    'Call a subroutine here to operate on the just-opened workbook
    With Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename) ' open and reference a new workbook
        add .Sheets.add ' call add passing it a reference to a new sheet in referenced workbook (i.e. the newly opened one)
        .Close True ' close referenced workbook saving changes
    End With
    Filename = Dir
Loop
```